# Given $x$ and $y$ are positive real numbers less than 9, what is the probability that the sum of them is greater than 3

Tags: probability

> Given $x$ and $y$ are positive real numbers less than 9, what is the probability that the sum of them is greater than 3

I thought that these are integers and did $\frac{_6C_2}{_8C_2}$ but then I realized that they are all the positive real numbers between $0$ and $9$, not just whole numbers.

And there are infinite real numbers between $x$ and $y$.

So, how can we find this probability?

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is a geometric proof. Find the area of the region $0\leq x \leq9$ and $0\leq x \leq9$, which is $81$. Then find the area within that region such that $x+y\geq3$.

This is the region you're looking for.

[image: Region of interest]

The easiest way to find its area is to subtract the area of the corner "cut off" from the square.

Comment: If this answer worked for you, you can accept it.

Comment: Note the implicit assumption: that the numbers are *uniformly distributed* over $(0;9)$.  The distribution was never mentioned in the problem, but we cannot proceed without one and this is the most reasonable assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables in question. Both are uniformly distributed on $(0, 9)$. We wish to find $P(X + Y \geq 3)$.

Such a probability can be found as follows: draw the square $(0, 9)^2$ in the plane. Now draw the line $x + y = 3$ and find the area above that line in the square and divide it by the area of the square. This gives you the desired probability - avoiding calculus.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of problem is best done by drawing a plane, put a line at $x=9$ and $y=9$. Then we want to know when $x + y \geq 3$ or rather when $y \geq -x + 3$, graph this line and shade the region appropriately and find its area. Then, take this area and divide by $81$, which is the area of the square that we are constrained to.